# creating a directive with parameter @

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my code:

```
restaurantApp.directive("formfield", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    $scope: {
        formType: "@"
    },
    template: '<input type="{{formType}}">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        alert(scope.formType);
    }
}
});
```

and in my HTML file:

```
 <formfield formType="{{inputType}}">
 </formfield>
```

and in my controller:

```
    $scope.inputType="password";
```

the problem is that i'm getting undefined value in my alert box instead of getting password to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `form-type` in your HTML not `formType`. You separate the words with a dash in the case of  scope variables defined in camel case inside your directive JS code when you pass value to them in HTML.

```
<formfield form-type="{{inputType}}">
 </formfield>
```

Also, an isolate scope is declared as `scope` not `$scope`, so the following

```
$scope: {
    formType: "@"
}
```

should change to:

```
scope: {
    formType: "@"
}
```

[Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHWeQVburiWDA8zBJLN0?p=preview).

Comment: see the plunk I posted.